# Find a subset of rows (N rows) in a Pandas data frame having the same values at a subset of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df which contains customer data without a primary key. The same customer might show up multiple times.

I have a field (df2['campaign']) that is an int and reflects how many times the customer shows up in the df. There are also many customer attributes.

In my example, going from top to bottom, for each row (i.e. customer), I would like to find all n rows (i.e. all n customers) whose values of the education and default columns are the same. Remember n is the int contained in df2['campaign']

So as shown below, for row 0 and 1 I should search 1 row but find nothing because there are no matching values for education-default combinations. 
For row 2 I should search 1 row (because campaign == 1) where education-default values match, and find 1 row in index 4.

```
df2.head()

job marital education   default campaign    housing loan    contact
0     3    1     0    0    1    0    0   1
1     7    1     3    1    1    0    0   1
2     7    1     3    0    1    2    0   1
3     0    1     1    0    1    0    0   1
4     7    1     3    0    1    0    2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `df2_sorted = df2.sort(['education', 'default'], ascending=[1, 1])`.
Then if your data is not noisy, the rows should become neighbors.